# C : Valgrind telling "Invalid write of size 4" but can't locate the problem

Tags: c, memory, valgrind, allocation

I'm fairly new to C and I can't locate an error I get while debugging with Valgrind. Here is the error I get.

```
==1987== Invalid write of size 4
==1987==    at 0x108C17: init_TSEQ (sequence.c:51)
==1987==    by 0x1089A8: main (main1.c:14)
==1987==  Address 0x51e5490 is 0 bytes after a block of size 880 alloc'd
==1987==    at 0x4C2BBEF: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:299)
==1987==    by 0x108B7E: init_TSEQ (sequence.c:38)
==1987==    by 0x1089A8: main (main1.c:14)
```

Apparently, the problem is coming from this function.

```
SEQUENCE *init_TSEQ(int nseq)
{
    DIR *D=opendir("sequences");
    struct dirent *entry;
    SEQUENCE *TSEQ=malloc(sizeof(SEQUENCE)*nseq);
    FILE *F;

    chdir("sequences");

    for(int i=0; (entry=readdir(D))!=NULL; i++)
    {
        if(entry->d_type==DT_REG)
        {
            char seq[MAXSIZE];

            F=fopen(entry->d_name, "r");
            fscanf(F, "%s", seq);
            TSEQ[i].lenght=strlen(seq);  // This is the line where the error comes from (l.51 in the code)

            for (int j=0; j<TSEQ[i].lenght; j++)
            {
                fscanf(F, "%c", seq);
                TSEQ[i].c[j]=seq[j];
            }

            fclose(F);
        }
    }

    closedir(D);

    return TSEQ;
}
```

And here is the SEQUENCE structure I'm using :

```
struct sequence
{
    int lenght;
    char c[MAXSIZE]; // MAXSIZE equals to 40
};

typedef struct sequence SEQUENCE;
```

As you can see in the function, I alloc'd memory for the TSEQ.lenght field in this line :

```
SEQUENCE *TSEQ=malloc(sizeof(SEQUENCE)*nseq);
```

So where did I lack memory allocation ?

Comment: probably `i` reaches `nseq` and so you write off the end of your allocation. The loop condition should check this. Also you don't seem to give the caller any way to know how many items were actually read

Comment: I tried changing the loop to :
'
((entry=readdir(D))!=NULL) && (i<=nseq)
'

But it changed nothing. The error definitely comes from :
'
TSEQ[i].lenght=strlen(seq);
'

As Valgrind says.

Comment: `i <= nseq` has the same problem as the original code: eventually `i` is equal to `nseq`. Change it to `i < nseq`

Comment: Thanks, I changed that

Answer (score 1):

So I managed to solve the problem by modifying the structure of the code :

```
SEQUENCE *init_TSEQ(int nseq)
{
    DIR *D=opendir("sequences");
    struct dirent *entry;
    SEQUENCE *TSEQ=malloc(sizeof(SEQUENCE)*nseq);
    FILE *F;
    int i=0;

    chdir("sequences");

    while(((entry=readdir(D))!=NULL) && (i<=nseq))
    {
        if(entry->d_type==DT_REG)
        {
            char seq[MAXSIZE];

            F=fopen(entry->d_name, "r");
            fscanf(F, "%s", seq);
            TSEQ[i].lenght=strlen(seq);

            for (int j=0; j<TSEQ[i].lenght; j++)
            {
                fscanf(F, "%c", seq);
                TSEQ[i].c[j]=seq[j];
            }

            fclose(F);
            i++;
        }
    }

    closedir(D);

    return TSEQ;
}
```

Comment: [man 3 readdir](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readdir.3.html) `"The readdir() function returns a pointer to a dirent structure representing the next directory entry in the directory stream...  RETURN VALUE On success, readdir() returns a pointer to a dirent structure. (This structure may be statically allocated; do not attempt to free(3) it.)"` Glad you figured out not to allocate for `entry`. All you were doing is creating a memory-leak by overwriting the pointer to you allocated entry.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this part